# Map function in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How can I use Map function in this component

[image]

My data is
[image]

I have try with

```
                       {
                                section.post.map((news,index)=> (
                                        (index <= 1) ?
                                            <div key={index} className="col-lg-6">
                                                <StyleTwo350X390 news={news}/>
                                            </div>

                                        : (index >=2) ?
                                            <div key={index} className="col-lg-6">
                                                <StyleFour350X82 news={news}/>
                                            </div>
                                        :null
                                    ))
                            }
```

but the actual result cannot get from this.
(I am beginner in react js)

Comment: what is with the conditions  here? And what are you expecting

Comment: 1st 2 item will in defrent two lg-6 then next 3item will in same one lg-6 see the 1st image